# Delay Command Block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have already asked a question about this but I didn't really get a clear answer.

I need to delay a tp command but when I searched it up I found a answer on how to tp an armour stand. I would like to know how to convert the command below so that it teleports a person to `-586.634 64 -430.697`.

This is the command I found

```
/tp @e[type=ArmorStand,name=Bob,score_time_min=101] ~ ~1 ~
```

If anyone could change this command or tell me how to it would really help!

*(NOTE: Before anyone comments below I did already create the scoreboard)*

Comment: well, if you want to teleport a person instead of an armorstand, you can use `@p` (closest person to the commandblock) or `@a` (all players) with the according selectors. you should possibly scrap `name` as well, in case you don't want to target only one specific player.

Comment: Don't re-ask [your question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/296260/how-to-delay-a-command-block).  Please be patient for answers, and if you don't understand one, ask for clarification there.  Re-asking your question means we just have to re-close it.

Comment: Sorry for asking twice

Answer (score -1):

You can create a delay by simply using repeaters (yup that's still a thing)!

Trigger --> delay -_- --> teleport command

Comment: I know but it needs to be compact

Comment: @user174432 how compact do you need it to be?